# Как накопить значения внутри функции, без второго параметра, по условию в objects может быть передан и кортеж

Tags: python-3.x

```
def universal_summ(*objects, total=[]):
    for i in objects:
        if not isinstance(i, list):
            total.append(i)
        elif isinstance(i, list):
            for j in i:
                universal_summ(j)
    return sum(total)

print(universal_summ([[1, 2, [3]], [1], 3]))
print(universal_summ([[1, 2, [3]], [1], 3]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow!

Вы можете создать переменую `result` с результатом выполнения функции и возвращать её. Чтобы сделать проверку на кортеж, вы так же можете использовать функцию `isinstance`

```py
def universal_summ(*objects):
    result = 0
    for i in objects:
        if isinstance(i, tuple) or isinstance(i, list):
            result += universal_summ(*i)
        else:
            result += i
    return result
```

Comment: Спасибо ОГРОМНОЕ я так делал только рекурсии не там вызывал мозг уже закипел!!!!!

Comment: @MTVMtv28 пожалуйста! буду рад, если вы отметите мой ответ, как правильный!)